# The user-left event is fired when unpublish method is called

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have a simple broadcasting test app.

I join a channel as host and eventually I unpublish.

```
this.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "live", codec: "h264", role: "host"});

//...then
await this.client.publish([this.audioTrack, this.videoTrack]);

//..eventually
await this.client.unpublish([this.audioTrack, this.videoTrack]);
```

This immediately fires the `users-unpublished` and `user-left` fires in the "audience" remote users.

This is not documented in the SDK.

How to prevent the `user-left` event being fired when the user has not really left the channel?

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of the agora-web-sdk-ng. When a host call “unpublish” to unpublish his local stream, his role is going to change from host to audience. And that will trigger the “user-left” callback.

“User-left” callback api: https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#event_user_left

“Unpublish” api: https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#unpublish

If you want to detect whether a user leave the channel instead of switching the roles, you can achieve that by implementing the RTM SDK. When a user joins the RTC channel (video call channel), he should also join the RTM channel with the same channel name as the one used for video call. Then you can use “getMembers” method in RTM SDK to retrieve a list of users in that channel.

“getMembers” api: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_cpp/classagora_1_1rtm_1_1_i_channel.html#a3f9c943059ac48a568c81798da38c3cb

Comment: Unfortunately, this is agora-web-sdk-ng. Removal of the stream is not considered the change of the role in the "live" mode.

Comment: I made some edits to the answer, hope this can answer you question.

Comment: Good effort. Please my own answer for better workaround

Answer (score 1):

The `user-left` is fired as a side effect of the SDK being developed. This effect is planned to be removed in the next version.

**One way to distinguish the user leaving verses unpublishing** is the `reason` argument of the event. The argument holds `BecomeAudience` if the event is fired when the host unpublish the media. Otherwise, the argument holds `Quit` or `ServerTimeOut`.

Also, then the reason for the event is "Becomeaudience", the `user-joind` event will fire after 10 seconds.

https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#event_user_left